# What do the downed penalty icons mean?

Tags: guild-wars-2

http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Death_penalty

So we know what it is, but in game next to your HP you get a little coloured skull which shows you have some 'downed penalty' points.

Does anyone know what the colours mean? Or how to know how many points you have? So far I've seen a white icon and a dark orange one.

[image: Skillbar]

Comment: I've done a little experimenting, and it looks the 4 levels are. White, Yellow, Orange and Red. After that it insta-gib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Wiki entry you linked explains, every time an opponent reduces your life to 0 you go down and have a bar that shows your remaining consciousness which gets lowered by time and attacks and increased if you get revived or call for help (the 4th skill). If you get revived or manage to call for help long enough, you get back into the fight. If it's empty, you are completely dead and can only get revived by another player or respawn at a teleport point.

The starting consciousness gets reduced by the death penalty. White means you start at 75%, Yellow 50%, Orange 25% and with red you die immediately, no call for help or rock throwing possible.

Comment: Where did you find the info about the colours and numbers?

Comment: The wiki entry you linked: "For each point, 25% will be removed from the starting consciousness bar the next time that character gets downed. [...] If a character goes down with 4 points of death penalty (ie. five times within one minute), they will go straight to the defeated state". So it has 4 points, which fits to the colors you yourself mentioned in the comment to the OP.

Comment: People always catch me out by reading stuff. I should learn to read at some point.

Comment: @DavidYell that makes the fact that you can type doubly impressive.

Comment: My guess? Speech-to-text.